# How to add list of Locations to Pushpins in WPF MVVM using Bing Maps

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, bing-maps, bing

I'm new at WPF. Im working on project with Bing Map in WPF MVVM. I have instaled "Bing Maps WPF Control" nugget and I would like read latitudes and longtitudes of different locations from my database and put some Pushpins on the map. Now i have solution how to put only one Pushbin in MVVM:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="CoordinateShower.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF"
    xmlns:help="clr-namespace:CoordinateShower.Helper"
    xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:CoordinateShower.ViewModel"
    Width="1000" Height="600"
    Title="MainWindow">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <loc:MapViewModel x:Key="MapVM"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <m:Map x:Name="CoordinateMap" ZoomLevel="6" Mode="Aerial" Focusable="True" Center="47.620574,-122.34942"
           CredentialsProvider="xxx">
           <m:Pushpin Location="{Binding Source={StaticResource MapVM}, Path=locat}"/>
    </m:Map>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MapViewModel
{
    Location locat = new Location { Latitude = 47.620574, Longitude = -122.34942 };
}
```

Now I would like to ask how to write code in xaml for get more Pushbins in the same time (i will put Locations into List). Thank You

Comment: You should use a [MapItemsControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapitemscontrol.aspx) and bind its `ItemsSource` property to a collection of view model items with a Location property. The `ItemContainerStyle` of the MapItemsControl would have a ControlTemplate with a Pushpin,